# SQL commands hangs on query when used with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation

I have the following commands that I run on MySQL on the Jira database:

```
SELECT LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY , REMOTE_ISSUE_KEY 
FROM AO_A912D8_SYNC_INFORMATION 
WHERE substr(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, 5) 
IN 
  (SELECT issuenum 
  FROM jiraissue 
  WHERE issuetype 
  IN
    (SELECT ID
    FROM issuetype
    WHERE pname = "Story"
    )
  )
;
```

This works like a charm, however, I'm not satisfied, as the length of the value in `LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY`is variable: EFW-12345 or FWAI-5432. So i would have to change to `substr(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, 5)` or `substr(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, 6)`

So I wanted to do something different and have the `WHERE IN` check the right string thanks to **`CONCAT()`**, instead of substracting a part of it.

As a draft, I first tried with that:

```
SELECT LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY , REMOTE_ISSUE_KEY 
FROM AO_A912D8_SYNC_INFORMATION 
WHERE LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY
IN 
  (SELECT CONCAT('EFW-',issuenum) 
  FROM jiraissue 
  WHERE issuetype 
  IN
    (SELECT ID
    FROM issuetype
    WHERE pname = "Story"
    )
  )
;
```

But this doesn't work, the query **goes on forever**

Note that it could do the query with something like that:

```
SELECT LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY , REMOTE_ISSUE_KEY 
FROM AO_A912D8_SYNC_INFORMATION 
WHERE LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY
IN 
  (CONCAT('EFW-','58276')) 
;
```

I also tried with more `()` around the `SELECT CONCAT()`, but it still put the database to search like crazy. CPU goes to 100%.

For information, the query at the second `SELECT` works:

```
SELECT CONCAT('EFW-',issuenum) FROM jiraissue WHERE issuetype IN (SELECT ID FROM issuetype WHERE pname = "Story" );
10610 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Here is how a sample of the data:

```
issuetype
ID      pname
10000   Epic
10001   Story

jiraissue
ID      issuenum    PROJECT issuetype 
154705  1942        12000   10001

project
ID      pname       pkey
12000   myproject   EFW

AO_A912D8_SYNC_INFORMATION
LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY REMOTE_ISSUE_KEY
EFW-1942        ABC-12354
```

Comment: what mean "as the length is variable."

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`

In your case: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, "-", 1)`

Don't use `CONCAT` because it's too heavy as you need to change all the result in subquery.

or even better:
`RIGHT(str, len)` -> instead of len, use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

Comment: Where do I use that one, in my example ?
It looks like the one I already have `substr()`

Comment: You can use it in substr(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, "-", 1)) so instead of using constant 5

Comment: Not exactly what I want. 
This allows to have the second part of the string `ABC-12345`, thanks to `SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY, "-", -1)` (with the minus to get the other side). 
But I would get some stuff that I don't want. 
For example, if I have `ABC-123` and `DEF-123`, it will get two times that 123. 
Thanks for the input still.  
I tried with `RIGHT` + `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, but it doesn't work

Comment: You're welcome. You mentioned only EFW-12345 or FWAI-5432. If you have ABC-123 and DEF-123 just check in where condition what you want to exclude...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big your tables are, i.e., how many jiraissues or projects store. But, have you tryed if this perform faster?

```
SELECT LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY , REMOTE_ISSUE_KEY 
FROM AO_A912D8_SYNC_INFORMATION 
WHERE LOCAL_ISSUE_KEY
IN 
  (SELECT distinct CONCAT('EFW-',issuenum) 
  FROM jiraissue 
  WHERE issuetype 
  IN
    (SELECT distinct ID
    FROM issuetype
    WHERE pname = "Story"
    )
  )
;
```